# SSL enabled TCP services on nginx-ingress causing SSL handshake failure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am running a zookeeper service with SSL in the k8s environment and exposing the same via Nginx ingress by specifying the ClusterIP port in the TCP-services configmap, This works fine. But the problem is that the Nginx does a TCP healthcheck every 5 seconds that causes SSL handshake failures at zookeeper since the Nginx does not have the necessary certificates with it. Is there a way to configure Nginx to use necessary certificates or to disable healthcheck altogether using the [TCP configmap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)

Comment: Do you use [nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/mergeable-ingress-types) or [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) as Ingress Controller ?

Comment: kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Comment: What do you think about uing a [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) service type instead of ingress-nginx ? You can use it to expose services that are running in the cluster by forwarding layer 4 traffic to worker nodes.
How did you install zookeeper and configure TCP healthcheck ?
In order to allow me to further investigate your issue, please provide a [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sure @matt_j, will try to set up a reproducible example on GitHub and share the link, meanwhile, to answer your question, the zookeeper was installed using helm and we have disabled the readiness and liveness check on the ZK, TCP healthcheck mentioned in the question is not set up by me, my theory was that ingress is doing this healthcheck since I have specified ZK as an upstream server , and about using LoadBalancer service type though I can explore that, since we have multiple services, all of them were exposed using ingress so it would be preferable to have ZK too behind the ingress

Comment: Could you please provide this reproducible example ?
Do you have Kubernetes on bare-metal or Managed Kubernetes Service ? 
Do you use [nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/mergeable-ingress-types) or [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) as Ingress Controller ?
I'm not sure what you mean by: `ingress is doing this healthcheck`.

Comment: Hi @matt_j, I am using amazon eks service, didn't get time setup a reproducible example, Will try to do it over this weekend, what I meant `ingress is doing this healthcheck` is that, the ingress seems to do a tcp connect on the port specified in tcp-configmap to check if the endpoint is active, which causes the SSL failure since ingress does not have access to client certificate.